# Iterating through an API with different category names using python and pandas

Tags: json, pandas, api, for-loop, request

i'm doing a school project where i need to iterate trough 16 categories (i already have them in a class list) to get all of the jokes from the API and i can't seem too do it.

I understand i need to iterate the request once for every category (in this case i already know they are 16 and i have a variable called "r" where they are stored.

I think i need to use for but can't seem to do it. And on top of getting the full list for the 16 categories i need to put them all in a new dataframe.

?? = is the category name to get (0:"animal", 1:"career", 2:"celebrity", 3:"dev", 4:"explicit", 5:"fashion", 6:"food", 7:"history", 8:"money", 9:"movie", 10:"music", 11:"political", 12:"religion", 13:"science", 14:"sport", 15:"travel")

```
import requests

url = "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/search"

querystring = {"query":"??"}

headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxxx",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

thx in advance

---- more detail (edit)

API to get category names:

```
import requests

url = "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/categories"

headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxx",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
a = response.text
a
```

Output:
'["animal","career","celebrity","dev","explicit","fashion","food","history","money","movie","music","political","religion","science","sport","travel"]'

And then instead of querying manually each category i'm trying to find a way to iterate all the categories and put all the outputs in 1 dataframe

```
import requests

url = "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/search"

querystring = {"query":"animal"}

headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxxxx",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

hope i was able to explain better what i'm trying to acomplish. thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what goes into the ?? but you need to iterate over a list. assuming your 'r' is dictionary use r.keys() or r.values(). This will collect all the responses into a list. You can then manipulate them into dataframes and concatenate. Without knowing the response.text format it's not possible to definitively say how to get that into pandas.

```
url = "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/search"
headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxxx",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
response_list = []
for s in list(r.keys()):
    querystring = {"query":s}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(response.text)
    response_list.append(response.text)
```

Comment: Hi, in the ?? goes the category name. If i manually write them one at a time i will eventually get all the values i need. What i would like to do is to have a function to iterate all the category names instead of doing it manually for each category. And then combine all the results into 1 dataframe

Answer (score 0):

first i converted the response list into a dataframe

```
df_chuck_categories = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=['category'])
```

using @Jonathan-Leon great help it worked perfectly. the *for s in* is doing the iteration and the API is returning all of the categories.

```
import requests

url = "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/search"
headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxxxxx",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
response_list = []
for s in list(df_chuck_categories['category']):
    querystring = {"query":s}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(response.text)
    response_list.append(response.text)
```